# NPX-CRA: creating react app, using npx throws an error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create a react app using npx command as follows

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

but this gives me an error saying

```
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\xampp\php ENOENT
```

I googled the error and stumbled upon some answers which suggesting to add npm path to system variables or adding system 32 path to system variables.

**My User Variables**

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

**My System Variables**

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

I am not familiar with node js much and facing difficulty understanding the answer available on the internet.

Can anybody explain the situation with appropriate answer?

Comment: What is "My User Variables" and "My System Variables"? What's in your .npmrc?

Comment: .npmrc file contains the following
`prefix=${APPDATA}\npm`

Answer (score 0):

Try out following commands to get the npx up and running:

```
- npm cache clean --force
- npm init
- npm install create-react-app
- npx create-react-app myapp
```